# Windows Phone 8 Leadbolt Setup

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, leadbolt

Hi I am currently running a music app on wp8 and I've hit a wall, I'm looking to ad adds to my app using lead bolt they don't have an sdk from windows phone 8 they just state "Place this link in a webview of your app or an iframe of your mobile web page where you want your LeadBolt app wall to appear."

im a complete novice when it comes to this, i have 2 questions

1) how do i go about setting it so a timed popup when the user has to click a X to get it off
2)i can't find anywhere to enter this code

any advice would be great
thanks

Comment: The question is still pretty blurry -- you should provide at least a bit more code or any other data you operate.
But if to speak of iframe, you can always add it into Webbrowser Control.

Comment: what sort of code would you require, could you advise me on how to impliment an iframe with an exit button

Comment: But the site with LeadBolt (if you mean this one) says they support Windows Phone. Which way do they do that? They must provide some html (or javascript) or what?

Comment: The Only Help With Site Gives You Is "Place this link in a webview of your app or an iframe of your mobile web page where you want your LeadBolt app wall to appear."http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_wall?section_id=**********

Comment: Ok, so, just add a Browser Control to your Windows Phone app layout and add an iframe with such link. Are you familiar with html/javascript web?

Comment: yes i know about html/js its C# i don't know about basically what I'm after is a timed popup with a little close button that contains that link I'm struggling with the programming i tried adding an i frame in a web browser in a popup and i couldn't get it to run please if anyone can help

Comment: What do you mean on "I couldn't get to run"? What exactly "couldn't"? Weren't you able to add the browser? Weren't you able to load anything there? Or you just don't know what to load there? You should be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

For banner ad you can use this snippet

```
webBrowser = new WebBrowser {Width = 320, Height = 50, IsScriptEnabled = true};
webBrowser.NavigateToString(
    @"<html>
            <head>
                <meta name='viewport' content='width=320, height=50' />

                <style type='text/css'>html, body {    margin: 0px;    padding: 0px;}</style>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=123456'></script>
            </head>
     </html>");
webBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

For app wall:

```
fullScreenAdBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_wall?section_id=123456",UriKind.Absolute));
```

You can specify the width and height as you need

One drawback with this integration is that you will show blank page when there are no ads. 
If you are fine displaying house ad, you can setup house ad in the portal. If you are not, you can overcome this limitation by adding house ad (including a script to notify you when house ad is displayed) and hide the web browser when you get the script notification you injected.